# Mpirun error with SLURM: "An ORTE daemon has unexpectedly failed", but only when passing parameters with sbatch

Tags: python, mpi, openmpi, slurm, sbatch

I get the following error when trying to submit a job with sbatch:

```
An ORTE daemon has unexpectedly failed after launch and before
communicating back to mpirun. This could be caused by a number
of factors, including an inability to create a connection back
to mpirun due to a lack of common network interfaces and/or no
route found between them. Please check network connectivity
(including firewalls and network routing requirements).
```

When I use sbatch with no parameters it runs fine, but when I try to pass any parameter (e.g. `--job-name` or `--export`) with sbatch, the above error appears.

I am using openmpi 3 and running a python script with mpirun. Both mpirun and orted appear to be using the same openmpi version, as evidenced by calling `which` in my slurm script right before using mpirun:

```
which mpirun: /opt/openmpi30/bin/mpirun
which orted: /opt/openmpi30/bin/orted
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.